# Error com.huawei.trustspace, 11 is illLegal. I want to access TrustSpace on the security screen

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, wechat, qq

I want to access TrustSpace on the security screen.

I'm using Unity and implemented login using wechat and QQ.

However, in Huawei Android 10, wechat and QQ are protected by the TrustSpace security feature.

Because of this, you cannot log in.

So, I was able to move to the security screen through android code, but not to the TrustSpace screen below.

In conclusion

1. Go to TrustSpace below the Security screen.
2. Unprotecting wechat and QQ within TrustSpace.

I want to control both of them with code, but I want to know how to do that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Step one, please open Huawei mobile phone, finding the `"Settings"` icon,  clicking to enter the main interface.

Step two, after entering the `“settings”` interface, choosing the `“security and privacy”` button on the screen.

Step three, selecting the `“Payment protection Center”` option in the new interface.

Step four, choosing the option of `“Payment protection Center”` and switching on. That’s it.

Here is a detailed picture and text introduction:https://www.kafan.cn/edu/20052152.html